# Error when loading locale on Angular using angularx-flatpickr

Tags: angular, locale, flatpickr

Added the locale to directive on angular component:

```
<input
type="text"
name="date"
mwlFlatpickr
[altInputClass]="'form-control'"
[(ngModel)]="post.date"
[altInput]="true"
[inline]="true"
[dateFormat]="'d.m.y'"
[locale]="'Portuguese'"
[defaultValue]="'today'"
[convertModelValue]="true">
```

When trying to load the locale, the erro is returned:

> Error: flatpickr: invalid locale Portuguese
>
> at setupLocale (flatpickr.js:1910) at init (flatpickr.js:581) at FlatpickrInstance (flatpickr.js:2419) at _flatpickr (flatpickr.js:2438) at flatpickr (flatpickr.js:2463) at FlatpickrDirective.push../node_modules/angularx-flatpickr/fesm5/angularx-flatpickr.js.FlatpickrDirective.ngAfterViewInit (angularx-flatpickr.js:295) at callProviderLifecycles (core.js:22416) at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.js:22390) at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.js:22380) at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23316)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your `module.ts` file, import all necessary files, create a function named `flatpickrFactory`, and import the language correspondent to your language ([All languages files are here](https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr/tree/master/src/l10n))

```
import { FlatpickrModule, FLATPICKR } from 'angularx-flatpickr';
import flatpickr from 'flatpickr';
import { Portuguese } from 'flatpickr/dist/l10n/pt';

export function flatpickrFactory() {
  flatpickr.localize(Portuguese);
  return flatpickr;
}
```

Now, on your `component.ts` import `flatpickrFactory();` to your `ngOnInit()` method.

```
ngOnInit() {
  flatpickrFactory();

  // Your other logic here...
}
```

And in your component.html (templateUrl), add the directive, like this example:

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  mwlFlatpickr 
  [(ngModel)]="selectedDate" 
  [altInput]="true" 
  [dateFormat]="'d.m.y'"
  [locale]="'Portuguese'"
  [convertModelValue]="true">
```